# how to display post when clicking the calender widget in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, calendar, widget

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/calendar-widget-how-to-display-posts-from-specific-category-only

I tried the above link.  In that link they have not given the code details.  I want to change the coding to link between posts and the calender widget.  How can I change this using code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this with a plugin.  This one says it does exactly what that URL you posted is trying to do.

[Calendar Category](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/calendar-category/)